# Error Building and installing local chainlink node

Tags: chainlink

I followed the steps listed on the
https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink#install
to install a local chainlink node.

---

I run the `make install` command to build and install the node and get an error

`Error: https://registry.npmjs.org/@material-ui/icons/-/icons-4.5.1.tgz: ESOCKETTIMEDOUT`.

Comment: Did you run yarn first?

Comment: I tried running `Yarn install` first. It works. The node is building. But when i did `make install` directly `Yarn install` was the first process that kicked in. I presumed that was enforcing the step itself.

Comment: So it’s working now? You just needed to run yarn?

Comment: the `make install` run is complete but now running `chainlink help` gives `zsh: command not found: chainlink`

Answer (score 0):

Try running Yarn install. Then to get the Chainlink command to work in your terminal you need to add the Chainlink binary to your PATH variable, check out this post on how to do that:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41542/adding-a-new-executable-to-the-path-environment-variable